# linter-ruby atom not working

Tags: ruby, atom-editor, lint

I just installed the linter-ruby package on atom and restarted the editor, but it doesn't detect any errors on my ruby files nor does it highlight the corresponding "end" to the "def"s. Is there something I'm missing? I have linter 1.11.21 and linter-ruby 1.2.4 installed. Below is a pic of all my packages install -

[image]

Comment: Do you have ruby installed?

Comment: yes, I do. I can confirm by typing `ruby -v` in terminal and it returns me the version number

Comment: If you meant the language-ruby and language-ruby-on-rails in atom packages, those are also installed in atom

Answer (score 0):

To get Linter to work for me (windows 7) with atom and ruby I installed these packages:  Busy-signal, intentions, linter, linter-ui-default (these 4 by steelbrain), & linter-ruby (AtomLinter)

Hope this helps!